# Simple JAX-RS example with @Consumes, @Produces and JAXB

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I'm trying to create and run simple example of JAX-RS using `@Produces`, `@Consumes` annotation and JAXB.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/hotel")
public class RestMain {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  @Path("{hotelId}")
  public HotelRESTInfo read(@PathParam("hotelId") long hotelId) {
    HotelDataSourceFake hotelDataSourceFake = new HotelDataSourceFake();
    HotelRESTInfo hotelInfo = hotelDataSourceFake.getFakePlaceById(hotelId);
    return hotelInfo;
  }
}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST App</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The second application which is the client.
Now I have the following client code:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
...
Client client = Client.create();
String uri ="http://localhost:8080/RESTJEE/rest/hotel/" + hotelId;
WebResource resource = client.resource(uri);
ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/xml").get(ClientResponse.class);
HotelRESTInfo hotelRestInfo = response.getEntity(HotelRESTInfo.class);
```

But I don't want to use jersey's Client, ClientResponse and WebResource.
I want to do this with `@Consumes`.
Should client appliaction `web.xml` contain some additional parameters?

Both sides (client and server) contain the `HotelRESTInfo` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class HotelRESTInfo {
...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you are mismatching something.

You have on one side the HttpClient that make requests, and on a other computer the HttpServer that build responses. It's basic and I suppose you get it.

The thing is that the `@GET read ()method` **consumes** the request body, and **produces** the response body.

So you can have :

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) //client sends also xml
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Path("{hotelId}")
public HotelRESTInfo read(@PathParam("hotelId") long hotelId) {
    (...)
}
```

Obviously, you would like that your *client consumes webservices*, so `@Consume` **definitively makes sense in the Client side**.

Unfortunately, JaxRS was built on the server side in 2008 or so, without thinking of synergies with a  Java client. And @Consumes is definitively a server annotation, and I haven't seen in the [documentation anything about reusing](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e573) annotations on the client.

The Jersey client is pretty recent, in an effort of the JaxRS 2 specifications. Your questions shows that these specs may be difficult to write !